# how to use django choice in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, django

i have choice field in user model:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
     ('M', 'Male'),
     ('F', 'Female'),
 )

gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M')
```

after serialize i get:
[image]

and in my template i want use radio buttons:

```
<div class="radio-item">
  <div class="label-text">Пол</div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male">
    <label for="male"><span></span> Male</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female">
     <label for="female"><span></span> Female</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use radios to do what? Question is lacking quite a few details. It doesn't appear that you have read the documentation for using radios in angular either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are getting data from API and binding to form. So in your case you could use `ng-model` over `radio` inputs.

But before that 1st thing you need to bind whole object to `$scope.user = data;`. Additionally I assumed that radio values would be `M` & `F`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="radio-item">
  <div class="label-text">Пол</div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" ng-model="user.gender" value="M">
    <label for="male"><span></span> Male</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" ng-model="user.gender" value="F">
     <label for="female"><span></span> Female</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , it helped :D

Comment: @AlexandrDomoryonok Glad to help you, Thanks :-)